# Python script fails execution on subprocess.run() call only when called from context menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, windows-10, subprocess

I have a python script that I want to call from the windows file browser context menu (https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/)

I am currently debugging calling it from the non-specific context (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell) with the command "python "D:\toolbox\mineAudio.py" 0"
(note python3 is on the path as python and the script is at D:\toolbox\mineAudio.py)

When I call the script from cmd it works as expected with that command, and when I make debug modifications to the script (adding os.system("pause") to random lines) I can verify it is running correctly up to the point it hits the line `meta=cmd(['ffmpeg','-i',target])` (line 46) where it instantly and silently fails (note ffmpeg is also on the path)

EDIT: it actually gets as far as line 15 `result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,startupinfo=startupinfo)`

I cant figure out why the program is failing there as that line works fine everywhere else I have tested the script from other than the context menu.

Here is the full script if you want to brows through it

```py
import subprocess
import os
import sys
from sys import argv
from tree import tree
#for command line use:
#mineAudo.py [prompt=1] [dir=cwd]
#first arg prompt will prompt user for dir if 1, otherwise it wont
#second arg is the directory to use, if specified this will override prompt, if not and prompt=0, current working dir is used
def cmd(command):
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
    result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,startupinfo=startupinfo)
    return result.stderr.decode("utf-8")
def stripStreams(meta):
    i=1;
    lines=[]
    while i>0 :
        i=meta.find("Stream",i+1)
        lineEnd=meta.find("\n",i)
        lines.append(meta[i:lineEnd])

    return lines
def mineAudio(streams):
    ret=[]
    for stream in streams:
        if "Audio:" in stream:
            start =stream.find("#")+1
            end=stream.find("(",start)
            ret.append(stream[start:end])
    return ret
def convDir(dirTarget):
    targets=tree(dirTarget)
    convList(targets,dirTarget)

def convList(targets,dirTarget):
        print(targets)
        #target="2018-05-31 06-16-39.mp4"
        i=0
        for target in targets:
            i+=1

            if(target[target.rfind("."):]==".mp4"):
                print("("+str(i)+"/"+str(len(targets))+") starting file "+target)
                meta=cmd(['ffmpeg','-i',target])
                streams=stripStreams(meta)
                streams=mineAudio(streams)
                count=0
                output=target[target.rfind("/")+1:target.rfind(".")]
                file=target[target.rfind("/")+1:]
                #print (output)
                try:
                    os.mkdir(dirTarget+"\\"+output)
                except:
                    pass
                for s in streams:
                    print("converting track "+str(count+1)+" of "+str(len(streams)));
                    count+=1
                    cmd("ffmpeg -i \""+target+"\" -vn -sn -c:a mp3 -ab 192k -map "+s+" \""+dirTarget+"\\"+output+"\\"+output+" Track "+str(count)+".mp3\"")
                print("moving "+target+" to "+dirTarget+"\\"+output+"\\"+file)
                os.rename(target,dirTarget+"\\"+output+"\\"+file)
                print("Finished file "+target)
            else:
                print("("+str(i)+"/"+str(len(targets))+") skiping non mp4 file "+target)

def prompt():
    while True:
        dirTarget=input("input target dir: ")
        convDir(dirTarget)



if __name__ == "__main__":
        sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)    
        if len(argv)>2:
                if os.path.isdir(argv[2]):
                    convDir(argv[2])
                else:
                    convList([argv[2]],os.path.dirname(argv[2]))
        elif(len(argv)>1):
                if int(argv[1])==1:
                    prompt()
                else:
                    convDir(os.getcwd())
        else:
            prompt()


        os.system("pause")
```

Note that I am not married to this particular implementation, any implementation with the same effect (extracting the .mp3 tracks from an .mp4 file automatically) would be fine too

also, here is the file Tree

```py
#Returns the paths of all files in a directory and all sub directories relative to start directory
import os
def tree(directory,target="f"):
    paths=[]
    for currentDir,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
        if target=="f":
            for file in files:
                paths.append(currentDir+"/"+file)
        if target=="d":
            #paths.append(currentDir)
            for dir in dirs:
                paths.append(currentDir+"/"+dir)
    for i in range(len(paths)):
        paths[i]=paths[i].replace("\\","/")
    return paths
```

Can anyone help me get this working?

**Edit:**
here is a shorter example code that crashes in the same way (still uses ffmpeg though)

```py
import subprocess
import os
def cmd(command):
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

    result = subprocess.run(command,stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,startupinfo=startupinfo)

    return result.stderr.decode("utf-8")


os.system("pause")

out=cmd(['ffmpeg','-i','D:\\ffmpeg test\\test\\2018-05-31 06-16-39\\2018-05-31 06-16-39.mp4'])
print(out)
os.system("pause")
```

(note the file is hard coded, program output should be
[image] )

Comment: I hope you trust your filenames -- there's more than ample opportunities for maliciously-named files to run arbitrary commands. Anyhow -- (1) if you can build a shorter [mcve] (removing code that isn't a mandatory element of causing the problem), that'll make this easier to investigate; (2) note that ffmpeg reads from stdin -- you might want to explicitly redirect it, even if from `subprocess.DEVNULL` or the like.

Comment: I trust the file names, but I do see your point, I should make sure they are sanitized anyway.  as for the minimal complete example, this should do

Comment: I added stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, didnt help :(

Comment: I don't actually recommend sanitization as an approach -- better to pass data out-of-band from code altogether -- but Windows doesn't give you that option (since each program is passed a single command-line string rather than an argv array), so... yeeeah. :/

Comment: (if this weren't Windows-centric, I'd take a shot at it; as it is, though, the platform is outside my area of expertise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to "solve" the problem by the round about hackish way of creating a batch file that calls the python script command, but this does seem a bit of a hack, and I would think there would be a better way.